# How to interpret this strange QQ plot?

Tags: r, qq-plot

I am trying to find the best distribution for my data, this is for the Pareto Distribution but it looks similar for inverse gamma and log-normal. It is around 22 million data points. It is definitely heavy-tailed. What does this mean, if anything?

[image: fitdistrplus output]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please tell us more about your problem and why you think it is important to give a name to your distribution.

Comment: I am trying to find a distribution that fits my data! It's important because this dataset can likely be used to inform ecological models, ergo it is important to me to attempt to fit distributions for future predictability, thanks.

Comment: Depending on the nature of your data, you might also want to look at the GEV (Generalized extreme value) distribution. This distribution is fitted to block-maxima i.e. the maxima of different sets of data points. The [Fisher-Tippet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Tippett%E2%80%93Gnedenko_theorem) theorem is based on this. 

The Generalized Pareto is used for data points above a certain threshold, the theorem is called the [Pickands-Balkema-de Haan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pickands%E2%80%93Balkema%E2%80%93de_Haan_theorem) theorem.

Comment: @Stochastic Thanks a lot for this!